# Dot symbol in "type" field of property definition operator

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt5.2

I am using Qt 5.2 and QtQuick 2.2.
In my project I have several modules that are placed in separated directories. My problem is that I can't use dot-separator in typename while defining properties.
For example:

MyRect.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
   id: root
   property color rectColor: "white"

   color: root.rectColor 
}
```

MyRectInRect.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import "./" as MyModule

Rectangle {
   id: root

   property MyModule.MyRect innerRect: MyModule.MyRect {  } 
   // ^ error: Unexpected token `.'; Unexpected token `identifier'
}
```

I have searched for something that could explain this behavior in the manual, but looks like there is nothing about it there. I guess that dot symbol is not allowed to be used in "type" field of property definition. But is there any way to explicitly define, what component from which module should be used as a type? Cause there may be need of declaring properties with same typenames, but from different modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: [QTBUG-10822](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-10822)